# Trying to get a valid integer from keyboard input

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to get a valid integer from the user input, the function I wrote must display an error message for these inputs..

1) 0 or a negative number

2) a string

It works for strings but not for 0 or negative numbers

I am unable to find my mistakes.. :-(

```
 public int getValidNumber()
    {
        int temp_int;
        while ((!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp_int)) && (temp_int > 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number....try again");
        }
        return temp_int;
    }
```

Is it the correct way to use  temp_int  variable immediately....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious mistake is that your while runs if the int is greater than 0, which you don't want:

```
//Assign to temp_int first:
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp_int);
while (temp_int < 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number....try again");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temp_int);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply works awesome.....But Can I know why my temp_int doesn't work inside while..?

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu I didn't run your code, but it might be because you have `&& (temp_int > 0)` when you want `&& (temp_int < 1)`. The way you have it, it will enter the loop for non-zero positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
getValidNumber(Console.ReadLine());
```

...

```
public int getValidNumber(string input)
{
  int temp_int = int.TryParse(input, out temp_int);
  if (temp_int =< 0)
  {
       Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number....try again");
  }
  return temp_int;
}
```

Comment: Yeah sure, put the while loop around the call to `getValidNumber(Console.ReadLine());` its good to make functions with business rules independent of the GUI (Console, Winform, ASP.Net, Mobile)...